# How to query internal transactions for an RSK transaction?

Tags: web3js, rsk

If I have the transaction hash of an RSK transaction, how can I get its internal transactions - i.e. when the smart contracts invoke functions on other contracts or do RBTC transfers?
I'm able to get the main transaction using web3.js, however once obtaining this,
I'm unable to parse it to extract the internal transactions that occur.
Another thing that I've tried was to use web3.js to query the block that the transaction occurred in, however was unable to parse this either to obtain internal transactions.

Comment: The RSK virtual machine (like the EVM) does not define "internal transaction", and hence there's no RPC to query them. You will need to "debug" the transaction execution in order to reconstruct these internals - which is quite difficult to do. Block explorers typically do this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reiterate my original comment:

> The RSK virtual machine (like the EVM) does not define "internal transaction", and hence there's no RPC to query them. You will need to "debug" the transaction execution in order to reconstruct these internals - which is quite difficult to do. Block explorers typically do this for you.

Fortunately the [RSK Block Explorer](https://explorer.rsk.co)
exposes an API, and thus is programmatically queryable.
So while you won't be able to use web3.js for this,
as you've asked for in your question,
you will be able to get internal transactions nonetheless.

Let's use an example, with the following transaction `0x01fbd670ea2455d38e83316129765376a693852eca296b3469f18d2a8dde35d8`, which happens to have **a lot** of internal transactions.

```sh
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H  "accept: application/json" \
  "https://backend.explorer.rsk.co/api?module=internalTransactions&action=getInternalTransactionsByTxHash&hash=0x01fbd670ea2455d38e83316129765376a693852eca296b3469f18d2a8dde35d8"
```

The above command retrieves the internal transactions of this particular transaction.
If you wish to do this for a different transaction,
simply change the value of the `hash` query parameter in the request URL.

This gives you a fairly large JSON response,
which I will not copy in full here.
You can then parse this using your JS code (since you're already using web3.js).

On the command line, you can explore the data a bit more using
the response filters available in the `jq` command line utility:

```sh
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H  "accept: application/json" \
  "https://backend.explorer.rsk.co/api?module=internalTransactions&action=getInternalTransactionsByTxHash&hash=0x01fbd670ea2455d38e83316129765376a693852eca296b3469f18d2a8dde35d8" \
  | jq -c '.data[].action.callType'
```

The above pipes the output of the `curl` command into `jq` which then
applies a filter that:

- looks at the `data` property, and returns all items in the array
- within each item drills down into the `action` object, and returns its `callType` value

This results in the following output:

```
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"staticcall"
"delegatecall"
"call"
```

So this transaction contains 18 internal transactions,
with a mix of `delegatecall`, `staticcall`, and `call`...
a fairly complex transaction indeed!

Now let's very the `jq` command to use a different filter,
such that we gets the full details on only the final internal transaction,
which happens to be the only `call` internal transaction:

```sh
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H  "accept: application/json" \
  "https://backend.explorer.rsk.co/api?module=internalTransactions&action=getInternalTransactionsByTxHash&hash=0x01fbd670ea2455d38e83316129765376a693852eca296b3469f18d2a8dde35d8" \
  | jq -c '.data[17].action'
```

Note that the only difference from the previous command is that now the filter
is `.data[17].action`.
This results in the following output:

```json
{
  "callType": "call",
  "from": "0x3f7ec3a190661db67c4907c839d8f1b0c18f2fc4",
  "to": "0xa288319ecb63301e21963e21ef3ca8fb720d2672",
  "gas": "0x20529",
  "input": "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",
  "value": "0x0"
}
```